# Regex to find content of the last occurence of square brackets

Tags: php, regex

**Hi Everybody,**

I'm Currently using preg_match and I'm trying to extract some informations **enclosed in square brackets**.

So far, I have used this:

`/\[(.*)\]/`

But I want it to be only the content of the last occurence - or the first one, if starting from the end!

In the following:

`string = "Some text here [value_a] some more text [value_b]"`

I need to get:

`"value_b"`

Can anybody suggest something that will do the trick?

**Thanks!**

Comment: Use `preg_match_all` and just the value you want. And more importantly: Make the quantifier lazy: `.*?`.

Comment: @FelixKling: no need for the lazy quantifier, just use a complemented character class -- see my answer. In fact, you should learn to _avoid_ lazy quantifiers when you can.

Comment: @fge: True, will be faster... he should still use `preg_match_all`.

Comment: Well, if it's only for the last match, no need -- let `.*` slurp it all and backtrack to find the first `[`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Match against:

```
/.*\[([^]]+)\]/
```

using `preg_match` (no need for the `_all` version here, since you only want the last group) and capture the group inside.

Your current regex, with your input, would capture `value_a] some more text [value_b`. Here, the first `.*` swallows everything, but must backtrack for a `[` to be matched -- the last one in the input.

Comment: **Fantastic! It works perfectly!**
I just had time to write my bio and got a perfect response…
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you are only expecting numbers/letter (no symbols) you could use `\[([\w\d]+)\]` with `preg_match_all()` and pull the last of the array as the end variable. You can add any custom symbols by escaping them in the character class definition.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! In my case, I'm retrieving two numbers separated by a forward slash, so I guess it wouldn't work. Plus I wanted to keep it simple. But it's good to know!

Comment: You can escape a forward slash into the character class definition `:)` So, something like `\[(\d+\/\d+)\]` for a number-slash-number

Answer (score 0):

`\[([^\]]*)\][^\[]*$`

See it [here on regexr](https://regexr.com/6f96u)

```
var someText="Some text here [value_a] some more text [value_b]";
alert(someText.match(/\[([^\]]*)\][^\[]*$/)[1]);
```

The part inside the brackets is stored in capture group 1, therefor you need to use match()[1](https://regexr.com/6f96u) to access the result.

For simple brakets, see the source to make this answer: [Regex for getting text between the last brackets ()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10459455/regex-for-getting-text-between-the-last-brackets)