# Regex for getting text between the last brackets ()

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I want to extract the text between the last `()` using javascript

For example

```
var someText="don't extract(value_a) but extract(value_b)";
alert(someText.match(regex));
```

The result should be

```
value_b
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try this

```
\(([^)]*)\)[^(]*$
```

See it [here on regexr](http://regexr.com?30rtn)

```
var someText="don't extract(value_a) but extract(value_b)";
alert(someText.match(/\(([^)]*)\)[^(]*$/)[1]);
```

The part inside the brackets is stored in capture group 1, therefor you need to use `match()[1]` to access the result.

Answer (score 10):

An efficient solution is to let [`.*` consume](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy) everything before the last `(`

```js
var str = "don't extract(value_a) but extract(value_b)";

var res = str.match(/.*\(([^)]+)\)/)[1];

console.log(res);
```

- `.*\(` matches [any amount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3206d374(v=vs.110).aspx) of [any character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) until the last literal `(`
- `([^)]+)` [captures](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) one or more characters [that are not](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `)`
- `[1]` [grab captures](https://stackoverflow.com/a/432503) of group 1 (first capturing group).
- use `[\s\S]` instead of `.` dot for multiline strings.

[Here is a demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/p0dGB3/2)

Answer (score 7):

```
/\([^()]+\)(?=[^()]*$)/
```

The lookahead, `(?=[^()]*$)`, asserts that there are no more parentheses before the end of the input.

Comment: this gives me the text and the bracket. (value_b).. I want the o/p to be value_b without the brackets..

Answer (score 0):

If the last closing bracket is always at the end of the sentence, you can use Jonathans answer. Otherwise something like this might work:

```
/\((\w+)\)(?:(?!\(\w+\)).)*$/
```