# JavaScript Regex return the last occurrence of y between x while ignoring double x's second occurrence

Tags: javascript, regex

Okay so the title must be a head scratcher, but here is the full string:

```
y = "_target"
x = "_"

string A = "prefix_param_name_id_set_selected_param_name_index__target_"
string B = "prefix_param_name_id_set_selected_param_name_index_target_"
```

1. regex looks for "y"
2. "y" will always be the value between the last occurrence of "x"
3. if the last occurrence of "x" is preceded with double "x" then regex assumes the second part of double "x" is part of "y"

so returning "y" where at one instance "y" may be "_target" and at another "y" may be "target"

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10459455/regex-for-getting-text-between-the-last-brackets) is where I am at:

```
var str = "prefix_param_name_id_set_selected_param_name_index__target_";
alert(str.match(/\(([^)]*)\)[^(]*$/)[1]);
```

returns "target"; it should be "_target".

**UPDATE:**

Please note that "y" is a variable and is unknown. str is known, but the regex does not know what "y" is, only that it is found between at the last occurrence of "x"

Comment: When I run `var str = "prefix_param_name_id_set_selected_param_name_index__target_";
alert(str.match(/\(([^)]*)\)[^(]*$/)[1]);` I get null

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `x` and `y` to create the regular expression

```
var y = "_target";
var x = "_";
var regexp = new RegExp("(?<=" + x + ")(" + y + ")(?=" + x + ")", "g");
var input = "prefix_param_name_id_set_selected_param_name_index__target_";
var matches = input.match(regexp);
```

`matches` outputs

> ["_target"]

**Explanation**

- Use `(?<=" + x + ")` to check if y follows `x`
- `(" + y + ")` captures `y`
- `(?=_)` checks if `x` follows `y` as well.

**Demo**

```js
var y = "_target";
var x = "_";
var regexp = new RegExp("(?<=" + x + ")(" + y + ")(?=" + x + ")", "g");
var input = "prefix_param_name_id_set_selected_param_name_index__target_";
var matches = input.match(regexp);
console.log(matches);
```

Comment: @zer00ne positive look-behind

Comment: I see, I am looking at it with JS eyes not as pcre

Comment: @zer00ne Sorry, *pcre*?

Comment: Perl Compatible Regular Expression is capable of look behind JS regex isn't.

Comment: Just keep in mind that "_target" is not known, it could be "_color" in one instance, and "_somethingelse" in another.

Comment: You will have to create regex accordingly

Comment: where do you actually apply var regexp ? its defined, but never used. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @JacquesJoubert Please check again, I have updated the code.

Comment: @gurvinder372 thank you for your input, appreciate it. Problem not solved yet, instead I decided a completely different approach.